How to play audio stream in JavaScript React app?
I am working on a web dialer system in my JavaScript NextUI React app. I am having some success an am able to successfully dial and hear my voice in my phone. However, when I speak through my phone, I am unable to hear it on my computer.
I am using Telnyx's WebRTC package. Once a call is connected, I am able to access the audio stream using the following code:
const stream = call.localStream;

How do I get this audio stream to play on my computer's speakers so I can hear the person on the other line of the phone speak?
